# Why does my Azure Queue-triggered Function appear to have incorrect parameters in TRACE logs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azureportal, azure-monitor

**Background:**

- I have a Queue-triggered Azure Function working in production.
- Since it handles processing files that are 1-2GB, it is set up to handle a **single queue at a time**.
- This is accomplished using the Function's `function.json` file:

[image]

**Issue:**

- The function is failing with "Timeout" error

  - I've seen this happen before when the Function crashes due to memory (Hence the fix above)
- In going through the "End-to-end transaction" details in Azure Portal, I see a series of settings that I'm concerned are overriding my `function.json` file:

[image]

- The `TRACE` logs *appear* to be showing a BatchSize of 16 and a NewBatchThreshold of 16, which depending on the size of files in the queue could crash the Function...
- Which is precisely what it does ~3mins later...

[image]

**Questions:**

- Where are these settings originating? (Because its not from `function.json`)
- How do I determine if this setting is crashing the Function?